# mysql subquery/nested query

Tags: mysql

Have I lost it, but if feels like I remember doing something along the lines of:

`select tb1.c1, (select count(tb2.c2) from tb2 where tb2.id = tb1.id) from tb1 where blah;`

I can't remember but I think did something like this maybe it wasn't mysql.

Comment: what exactly is your question or problem?

Comment: I am trying to ascertain the correct syntax for this type of query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was the question?

This statement looks valid, at least in MySQL 5.1 and later.

This may work in MySQL 5.0, but for sure not in MySQL 3.23.

You likely want to add an alias following the subquery, eg.  `) AS tb2_count from`